# How many natural attacks / damage can I do in one full round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, barbarian

So I'm building a new 5th level character and I'm going all in for STR built natural attacks character.

Race: Half-Orc (Toothy) 
Urban Barbarian (2lvl)  / Shapeshifting Ranger (3lvl)
I rolled 18 in STR + 2 + 1. Totalling 21 in STR at level 5.

If my GM allows me to pick Bloodrage Powers, I'll go for:

Feats / Rage powers

- Power Attack
- Lesser Abyssal Blood (2x claws 1d6, Primary attack)
- Extra Rage Power, Lesser Fiend Totem (Gore attack 1d8, Primary attack)
- Abyssal Blood (grow one size category larger)

I also will have an Amulet of Mighty Fists (Flaming +1d6)

So the scenario is that I'm raging and shapeshifting (+8 in STR) giving me a +12 to hit.
If all my attacks hits, I'm looking at:

> 3d6(2 claws, rend)
>   + 1d4(bite)
>   + 1d8 (gore)
>   + 4d6(flame)
>   + 36 (4 x str) 
>   + 18 (4 x pow att)
>
> **Totalling 63-108**

and if I use Abyssal  Blood and grow one size larger, I get

> 3d8(2 claws, rend)
>   + 1d6(bite)
>   + 2d6 (gore)
>   + 4d6(flame)
>   + 40 (4 x str) 
>   + 20 (4 x pow att)
>
> **Totalling 70-126**

Now if I get **Amplified Rage** feat, I'll get another +4 in STR....

Is this possible? That's an insane amount of damage for a 5th level character.

Comment: Is this a thought experiment, or something your are actually going to try?

Comment: Enjoy it while it lasts. It's a barbarian, the staple damage dealer. Natural attacks are notoriously difficult to upgrade and you seem to have used most of the tricks (size increase, pumping strength, getting more attack etc.), so I would expect that your character plateaus at lvl 10 or so, when the spellcasters overtake him with utility and save-or-die spells. Also, damage is not everything. It does not matter if you can kill enemies easily if they massacre your healer while you're still running to meet them.

Comment: Yup, I'm planning on trying this @ruut. Well, how much can a lvl 10 fighter output? I still can get Pounce, Improved Natural Attack, Vital strike, Imp. Vital strike ++

Comment: It's all fun and games until you fail a will save.

Comment: @Steven You're already committed to a Fiend Totem, you won't be able to use the Beast Totem at the same time. Also, when you run out of rage it won't look just as good. Lvl 10 Fighter will be nowhere near your numbers, but with a polearm and Trip, Reposition, Bull Rush etc. will have much greater control over the battlefield without sacrificing his core damage output.

Comment: Which rage power belongs to the Beast Totem? Abyssal Blood belongs to Blood Rage Powers.

Comment: I can't provide a complete answer (and you've already accepted one in any case), but some things need clarification as I see it. Feel free to ignore this comment if you aren't interested. Here are my points: Aren't Byte and Gore NA's use the same body part to begin with? Also, your attacks won't all remain primary attacks if you full attack with them. So 0.5 Str only for all that follow the first (or the first pair). Attacks becoming secondary also will affect your PA damage.

Comment: No, as long as it states that it is a Primary Attack, you get full BAB and STR bonus. When it comes to Bite and horns, you might actually be right. One of them will become secondary

Comment: Checked that out. They realy have changed it from 3.5, sorry. So there is only Byte+Gore issue left. It is stated clearly that you can't use manufactured weapon and NA from the limb holding a weapon in the same full attack. I think it is also true for two NA's provided by the same limb (head in your example).

Comment: I thought that at first as well, and from what I could find, they are both Primary still.  

I'd still take a level fighter with a polearm any day over this Barbarian, but it looks good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main advantadge on any Martial character after level 5 is iterative attacks.  Using a barbarian with these starts will definitely let you get an early start with reduced power as you level higher.

Shifter's Blessing doesn't kick in until Ranger level 3, which will give you 2 levels of Barbarian at level 5.

This means you'll have a total of 4 Feats + 1 rage power.  I would suggest taking Power Attack at level 1, [Rending Claws](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/rending-claws-combat) at 2nd, Extra Rage Power at 3rd (Assuming you have a level of Barbarian by now), and Amplified Rage at 5th.

[Improved Natural Attack:Gore](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/improved-natural-attack) is worth looking into as your level 7 feat as well.

This will make sure that you do have Rend with your claws, and that while shifted and Raging, you will have a +13 to hit with all attacks, or +11 while Power Attacking.

This however won't let you gain extra attacks as your BAB increases at later levels, and there are a couple of issues.

Abyssal Blood is a level 6 power, and as such can only be taken by a character with 6 class levels in Barbarian.

> The middle blood rage power (that without "lesser" or "greater" in the title) can only be taken by a 6th level or higher barbarian that already has the lesser blood rage power of its group.

If you were to compare your single attack damage against a fighter of a similar level, I think you would fall short of damage in a case by case basis, though as your build focuses on Full Attacks, this is an acceptable turnover.

On any given attack vs a monster with 17AC, you've got about a 25% chance of missing.  Assuming you hit every attack, you'll be dealing around 70-80 damage with a full attack, and at most with one attack, you'll hit 26 with your Gore.

This [AnyDice Link](http://anydice.com/program/6a12) will show the average damage you can expect for each attack.